# Child process cannot read after the exiting of parent process

Tags: c, unix, process

After forking and executing a child program by function `execvp()`, the parent process exit. However this cause the function `fgets()` in the child process return immediately without waiting for input from `stdin`.

I guess the exiting of the parent process will send some signals to the child process which make the `fgets()` function return. Could some one explain more for me?

Code of child program:

```
/* cc child.c -o child */

int main () {
  char buffer[10];
  fgets(buffer, 10, stdin);
  printf("This is what child program read:\n%s", buffer);
}
```

Code of parent program:

```
/* cc parent.c -o parent */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else if (pid == 0) {
    execvp(*(argv+1), argv+1);
  }
  else {
  //    while(1);  if while(1) or wait() is used, child process can wait for input
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

In zsh shell:

```
zsh>: ./parent ./child
zsh>: This is what child program read:   // read nothing and print nothing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminal is controlled by the foreground process group.  When the shell invokes the parent, it makes the parent the leader of the foreground process group.  The child inherits that group and has access to the terminal.

However, when the parent exits, the shell takes back control of the terminal and becomes the leader of the foreground process group.  The child is no longer in the foreground process group, so it has no access to the terminal.  In this case, `fgets()` will return `NULL` and an error code will be set.

If you take input from someplace other than the terminal, such as a pipe, then you'll see that the program works as expected.  For example:

```
$ echo test | ./parent ./child
```

So this problem only occurs when input comes from the terminal.

**In retrospect**, answering this question would have been more straighforward if the fgets error code was checked.  In this case, fgets returns null, but then you need to check `feof()` and/or `ferror()` to determine if this means that the end of the file was reached (stdin closed) or there was an error.  In this case, the NULL meant there was an `EIO` error.

*Earlier **wrong** answer (see comment thread for explanation, leaving this here because of the lengthy discussion):
When you fork, the child process inherits stdin etc.  When the parent process exits, it closes stdin, so the child tries to read from a closed descriptor and gets nothing.  By adding the call to `wait()`, you keep stdin open and this allows your child program to work as expected.*

Comment: This sounds plausible, but I'm think it is wrong (though the child certainly seems to get EOF). The file descriptors are private to each process, but there is an open file description that they share in common.  However, when a process exits, its file descriptors are closed, but POSIX says: _When all file descriptors associated with an open file description have been closed, the open file description shall be freed._ The parent exiting should not be able to affect the file descriptors in the child process (they should remain open).

Comment: If thats true, then why is parent process still able to read  from `stdin` even after the child has terminated? I mean won't the child close `stdin` when terminating?

Comment: @jdigital Well I modified and checked, and it was indeed able to read!

Comment: @nitish712 Good question.  The child doesn't actually terminate until the parent closes the child's process descriptor.  Since the code here doesn't explicitly close the descriptor, it means the child doesn't get closed until the parent exits (in other words, the child doesn't exit until the parent exits).  You should be able to use `ps` to check this out.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The doc I found for `fork` says _the two descriptors share open file status flags_ (although I grabbed this from the top result from Google, not from Posix ;-).  Your quote says the descriptor can't be freed (which makes sense since both processes are pointing to it), but it doesn't say the descriptor can't be closed.

Comment: @jdigital You're right. "ps -a" shows a Z status for the child process, which means the child process is a "defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler A simple test would be to have the parent explicitly close stdin before waiting.  If the child still works properly, then my theory is wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Leffler If I make the parent process exit when the child process is sleeping, the child process will read some strange characters from the STDIN file descriptor, which means the exiting of the parent process do affect the file descriptors in the child process.

Comment: @jdigital: the file descriptor can be closed by either process without affecting the file descriptor in the other; the file offset is shared; the file description is shared.  I'm still not quite sure what's going on; it wasn't the behaviour I was expecting.  If you redirect from a big enough file, both parent and child can read from the file independently.  'Big enough' means that whichever gets there first reads the first BUFSIZ bytes, and the file has to be bigger than that.  …

Comment: … There's a comment in [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) that _The behavior of multiple concurrent reads on the same pipe, FIFO, or terminal device is unspecified._  I'm not sure whether that's what we're seeing.  With sleeps around, either process can read and then the other, depending on where the sleeps are.

Comment: @jdigital, It seems like you read `fork(2)` manpage of Linux. In the same paragraph: The child inherits **copies** of the parent's set of open file  descriptors.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If the parent and the child write() to a same file instead of read(), everything is ok(With the parent process exiting first and closing the file descriptor). It seems that the strange thing we are seeing is associated with the read() function.

Comment: I have come up with a different theory and placed it into the original answer.

Comment: @jdigital This also explain why write() works but read() doesn't. A background process can write to the terminal but cannot read from the terminal.

Comment: @jdigital When I use isatty() to check the stdin file descriptor of the child process, isatty() returns 1 which means that the file descriptor does refers to a terminal. However according to your new theory, the child has no access to the terminal...

Comment: The child is still tied to the terminal (you'll see that with `ps` also) but the child is not allowed to access the terminal input stream.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47546/discussion-between-nmzzz-and-jdigital)

Comment: Well done on getting this sorted. This makes sense; any of the experiments I did tie in with this (from what I can remember 8 hours later).

Answer (score 0):

You should check the return value from fgets() before printing buffer. Check if fgets doesnot return NULL, and then only print the buffer.

Comment: Yes, I should check the return value from fgets() before printing buffer, but what I don't understand is why it return NULL. @jdigital has given the answer.