# Child process cannot read from terminal after it's parent exit

Tags: c, linux, bash, process, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                             
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int pid = -1; 
    char buf[10] = {0};

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
    }   
    if (pid == 0) {//child
        printf("[child]sleeping\n");
        sleep(2);//sleep to wait parent exit;
        write(1, "[child]nihao\n", 13);
        if (read(0, buf, 1) == -1) {
            printf("[child]ops, read error\n");
        }
        _exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("[parent]exit\n");
        //if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        //     perror("waitpid error\n");
        //}
        _exit(9);   
    }   
}
```

This program will output:

```
Jason at Jason-ubuntu in ~/c/more
○ ./fd-on-close 
[parent]exit
[child]sleeping

Jason at Jason-ubuntu in ~/c/more
○ [child]nihao
[child]ops, read error
```

### 9423 is child's PID

```
╰─○ ls -la /proc/9423/fd/
total 0
dr-x------ 2 sunan sunan  0 Oct 30 19:57 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 sunan sunan  0 Oct 30 19:57 ..
lrwx------ 1 sunan sunan 64 Oct 30 19:57 0 -> /dev/pts/33
lrwx------ 1 sunan sunan 64 Oct 30 19:57 1 -> /dev/pts/33
lrwx------ 1 sunan sunan 64 Oct 30 19:57 2 -> /dev/pts/33
```

There is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793755/child-process-cannot-read-after-the-exiting-of-parent-process) asked the same question, but I want to know more details about it, like how to force the child take control the terminal, how to see the progess group infomation mentioned in that thread, and who is taking control of the terminal, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The parent process is controls the terminal. The child process does not controls the terminal. So, the parent process dies, the child process goes to background. And the init takes that child process and add that into that childs. So, only the child does not controls the terminal.

If you want to do that you can use the tcsetpgrp funciton to do the child has take the controlling terminal.

If the parent dies the session_leader takes the terminal control.