# why getchar() in the child is not executed?

Tags: fork

```
pid = fork();
if( pid == 0)
{
    getchar();
    printf("Hello From Child\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Hello From Parent\n");
}
printf("Hello From %d\n",getpid());
```

This is the output that I get:

```
root@debian:/home/test#./a.out
Hello From Parent
Hello From 2370
root@debian:/home/test# Hello From Child
Hello From 2371
```

The printf statement in the child is executed before getchar() ?

Comment: Hoping to have an answer to the question plz.

Answer (score 0):

It is executing, and in the expected sequence, but it looks like you are feeding it with a white-space character (return.)

If there is something in `stdin` for `getchar()` to read when it executes, the output is a little cleaner:

```
jameson@lime:~$ echo 'a' | ./a.out 
Hello From Parent
Hello From 10312
Hello From Child
Hello From 10313
```

Comment: But there is nothing supposed to be in the stdin buffer. As a clue to that, if I just swap the getchar() between child and parent, getchar() causes the parent to block waiting for input before printing "Hello From Parent"

Answer (score 0):

The call to `getchar` in your code **is executing**, but *it does not read anything*. It returns an error that goes unchecked. The reason for the error is that after the parent process exits (after printing its pid), the child is kicked out of the foreground group when the shell gets back control (full explanation here: [Child process cannot read after the exiting of parent process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793755/child-process-cannot-read-after-the-exiting-of-parent-process)).

Here is a bunch of working code with the error checking that was missing:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int errno;

int main (void) {

    int c, errnum;
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        c = getchar();
        errnum = errno;

        if (c != EOF)
            printf ("getchar says %d\n", c);

        if (feof (stdin))
            printf ("no input from stdin!\n");

        if (ferror (stdin)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "stdin error: %s\n", strerror (errnum));
        }

        printf("Hello From Child\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Hello From Parent\n");
    }

    printf("Hello From %d\n",getpid());
    
}
```