# How to prevent parent process from losing console input after the child dies?

Tags: c++, input, terminal, pipe, fork

I'm trying to make a wrapper around an interactive program. For this I use the combination of `pipe`, `dup2` and `poll`. All seems to go well until the child terminates. At this step the parent process appears to lose its `stdin`, which is what I can't seem to understand why.

Here's the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct SystemFunctionFailure
{
    std::string what;
    SystemFunctionFailure(std::string const& what) : what(what) {}
};

template<typename T,size_t N> constexpr size_t countof(const T(&)[N]) { return N; }

void readAndPrint(std::string const& what, int fd)
{
    std::cerr << "Reading "+what+"\n";
    std::vector<char> buffer(1024);
    const auto bytesRead=read(fd,buffer.data(),buffer.size());
    if(bytesRead==-1)
    {
        if(errno!=EAGAIN)
            throw SystemFunctionFailure("read "+what);
    }
    else if(bytesRead==0)
    {
        std::cerr << "EOF reached on "+what+"\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "CONTENTS OF "+what+": "+std::string(buffer.data(),buffer.size())+"\n";
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int pipeChildOut[2];
        if(pipe(pipeChildOut)==-1) throw SystemFunctionFailure("pipe for child stdout");

        int pipeChildErr[2];
        if(pipe(pipeChildErr)==-1) throw SystemFunctionFailure("pipe for child stderr");

        int pipeChildIn[2];
        if(pipe(pipeChildIn)==-1) throw SystemFunctionFailure("pipe for child stdin");

        const auto child=fork();
        if(child==-1) throw SystemFunctionFailure("fork");

        if(child)
        {
            dup2(pipeChildOut[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(pipeChildOut[0]);
            dup2(pipeChildErr[1],STDERR_FILENO);
            close(pipeChildErr[0]);
            dup2(pipeChildIn[0],STDIN_FILENO);
            close(pipeChildIn[1]);
            execlp("sh","sh","-c","sleep 1; echo Test ; sleep 1; echo Child is exiting... >&2",nullptr);
            throw SystemFunctionFailure("execlp returned");
        }
        else
        {
            const int childStdErr=pipeChildErr[0];
            const int childStdOut=pipeChildOut[0];
            dup2(pipeChildIn[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
            fcntl(childStdErr,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);
            fcntl(childStdOut,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);
            fcntl(STDIN_FILENO,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);

            while(true)
            {
                std::cerr << "New iteration of IO loop\n";
                pollfd pollfds[]={ // making the indices coincide with .._FILENO
                                  {STDIN_FILENO,POLLIN},
                                  {childStdOut,POLLIN},
                                  {childStdErr,POLLIN},
                                 };
                if(poll(pollfds,countof(pollfds),{-1})==-1)
                    throw SystemFunctionFailure("poll");
                std::cerr << "poll returned\n";

                for(unsigned i=0;i<countof(pollfds);++i)
                    std::cerr <<" pollfds["<<i<<"].revents: " << pollfds[i].revents << "\n";

                if(pollfds[ STDIN_FILENO].revents&POLLIN) readAndPrint("stdin" ,pollfds[ STDIN_FILENO].fd);
                if(pollfds[STDOUT_FILENO].revents&POLLIN) readAndPrint("stdout",pollfds[STDOUT_FILENO].fd);
                if(pollfds[STDERR_FILENO].revents&POLLIN) readAndPrint("stderr",pollfds[STDERR_FILENO].fd);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SystemFunctionFailure& ex)
    {
        perror(ex.what.c_str());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Here the child closes its original `stdin` implicitly via `dup2`, so it seems it shouldn't affect any accesses of the parent to the console input. But for some reason here's what I get as output:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++14 && ./test
New iteration of IO loop
poll returned
 pollfds[0].revents: 0
 pollfds[1].revents: 1
 pollfds[2].revents: 0
Reading stdout
CONTENTS OF stdout: Test

New iteration of IO loop
poll returned
 pollfds[0].revents: 0
 pollfds[1].revents: 0
 pollfds[2].revents: 1
Reading stderr
CONTENTS OF stderr: Child is exiting...

New iteration of IO loop
$
```

I.e. I get the shell prompt, so the parent isn't in the foreground anymore. After this, if I wait several seconds and type a letter, I get this output:

```
poll returned
 pollfds[0].revents: 1
 pollfds[1].revents: 0
 pollfds[2].revents: 0
Reading stdin
read stdin: Input/output error
```

I'd like to at least have the parent process retain access to its console input after the child dies. After reading [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21794162/673852), I think my problem is related, but that answer doesn't answer my question: "How to do it right?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `if(child)` should be `if(child == 0)`.

From https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent,
>   and **0 is returned in the child**. On failure, -1 is returned in the
>   parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.