# Junk values after scanf child process

Tags: c, scanf, fork, system-calls

my `scanf` statement, in a child process, does not work properly:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int operando, operatore;

    pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 == 0) { // Figlio 2

        printf("Inserisci due numeri: ");

        scanf("%d%d", &operando, &operatore); //even though I " %d%d"...

        printf("Operando is %d and operatore is %d\n", operando, operatore);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wMP9.png)

- How do I fix?

Comment: Add `wait(NULL);` call to the parent process just before the `return 0;`.

Comment: Here is the reason why the `wait` is needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793755/child-process-cannot-read-after-the-exiting-of-parent-process

Comment: Also - **always** check the return value from input functions such as `scanf()`.

Comment: per the 'error' link, you did not enter the two expected integer values, so the call to `scanf()` failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question for an explanation of what is happening in your program: [Child process cannot read after the exiting of parent process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793755/child-process-cannot-read-after-the-exiting-of-parent-process). The most important part:

> The terminal is controlled by the foreground process group. When the shell invokes the parent, it makes the parent the leader of the foreground process group. The child inherits that group and has access to the terminal.
>
> However, when the parent exits, the shell takes back control of the terminal and becomes the leader of the foreground process group. The child is no longer in the foreground process group, so it has no access to the terminal.

To get your program to work as expected, add a `wait` call in the parent process to ensure the parent process does not exit until the child process has completed thus keeping the terminal available for the child.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int operando, operatore;

    pid_t pid2 = fork();

    if (pid2 == 0) { // Figlio 2
        printf("Inserisci due numeri: ");    
        scanf("%d%d", &operando, &operatore); //even though I " %d%d"...    
        printf("Operando is %d and operatore is %d\n", operando, operatore);
    } else if (pid2 > 0) {
        wait(NULL);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Note, some other general improvements to consider:

- Always check the return value of function calls. `scanf` in particular should be checked before using the results in the `printf`. Similarly the `fork` return value should be checked for error.

Comment: FYI, I didn't directly dup to the referenced question because it explains what the problem is but does not provide the specific solution for this question.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `scanf()` failed.  The code could have known this if it had checked the returned value of `scanf()`  Any returned value other than 2 would indicate an error occurred.

The scan() failed on the first 'input format conversion` specifier, so it never looked at the second 'input format conversion' specifier.

When a integer 'input format conversion' specifier in a call to `scanf()` fails, the target variable is set to 0.   The second variable displays what ever trash was in memory at its' location on the stack.